# PS2 emulator showing only the upper half of the game

Tags: emulation, pcsx2

I just installed on a brand new PC the ps2 emulator (pcsx2 1.4.0) and I'm having the following error. Whenever I launch a game it only shows the upper half of the game screen

I haven't changed any of the original settings the emulator has by default. And i'm using the BIOS: USA v01.60 (SCPH-39001_BIOS_V7_USA_160).
What could be the problem and how can I fix it?

The first image is what I get when I run the game, Even if I go full screen, the game is still only half visible. The second image is a screenshot of how the menu should look like (without the quit to windows option obviously).

[image: Screenshot of the game running on the emulator.]

[image]

Comment: you might need to explain you're problem in more detail as i don't think i'm the only one who doesn't know what that game is and just from your screenshot there doesn't seem to be anything wrong

Comment: @Memor-X you are absolutely right, My screenshot wasn't representative of the game nor the issue im having.

Comment: @Memor-X NO, he explained well enough his problem. He provided a screenshot showing the problem and the game

Comment: @GamerM [not in the original version of the question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/revisions/333853/1) which is the context of my comment

Comment: Why are you in 640x567? What's you native resolution? If you haven't changed any of the original settings the emulator has by default, you're [not trying hard enough](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/254799/how-do-i-fix-audio-emulation-on-pcsx2/254835#254835).